# Axon4 - Re-queue failed messages

Tags: axon

In below scenario, what would be the bahavior of Axon -

- Command Bus recieved the command
- It creates an event
- However messaging infra is down (say kafka)

Does Axon has re-queing capability for event or any other alternative to handle this scenario.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using Axon, you know it differentiates between Command, Event and Query messages. I'd suggest to be specific in your question **which** message type you want to retry.

However, I am going to make the assumption it's about events, as your stating Kafka. 
If this is the case, I'd highly recommend reading the [reference guide](https://docs.axoniq.io/reference-guide/extensions/kafka) on the matter, as it states how you can uncouple Kafka publication from actual event storage in Axon.

Simply put, use a `TrackingEventProcessor` as the means to publish events on Kafka, as this will ensure a dedicate thread is used for publication instead of the same thread storing the event. Added, the `TrackingEventProcessor` can be replayed, thus "re-process" events.

Comment: Thanks Steven ! you guessed it right, my query was for event. Have updated the query the question

Comment: Thanks for that @PrashantShandilya! If my answer resolved your problem, would you mind marking it as the answer too?